# Strange problem with document.getElementsByTagName("a")

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't it recognise 'number' as a variable in the following code, second line?

```
var number = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[number].href;
```

Of course it works with any real number instead of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the array returned by `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` is 0-based, so, by definition, the index you're seeking doesn't exist.  I suppose you probably mean this:

```
var number = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[number-1].href;
```

:)

edit:

try using firebug to dump the values to the console for debugging - the problem will quickly become obvious :)

```
var number = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
console.log("number = "+number);
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[number-1].href;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. in retrospect a very silly mistake. Whatever, thank you :D

Comment: Why call `getElementsByTagName` twice?? Call it once into local variable then use it. Basic optimization. :)

Comment: Did that already... I only ever changed it because I thought there was something wrong in the very code I used, it's optimised now :)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript arrays are zero-based, so, you will need to use `number-1` to get the last element.